# How to change Kendo MVC grid's edit command template?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC. I have grid with edit command. The default look of the edit command is "button" and i wanted to change it to link. But there is no Template() method for command. So how do i change the edit command button to link?

Telerik has option to create own custom command as defined [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-command). but my grid is configured to use `GridEditMode.Popup` which works great with inbuilt edit command. If i create custom command then i guess i have to wireup popup window & everything else.

I just wanted to change "button" to link?

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<UI.Models.GridVM>()
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.CampaignID)                    
            columns.Bound(p => p.CampaignStatus);  
            columns.Command(command => command.Edit().Text("Edit Me")); // How do i change this to link??
        })            
        .Editable(editable => editable
            .Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
            .TemplateName("CampaignEdit")
            .Window(w =>
            {
                w.Width(400);
                w.Title("Edit Details");
            }))
        .Filterable()
        .Pageable()
        .Navigatable()
        .Sortable()                      
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .PageSize(20)
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.CampaignID))
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetCampaigns", "Home"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateCampaign", "Home"))
        )            
    )
```

**UPDATE1**
@Steve Greene Thanks. Your approach did work on master grid. But i also have child detail grid which has edit link. The approach didnt work for detail grid. Kendo throws error.
I think we have to escaped template expression, to be evaluated in the child/detail context. But i am not sure the whats the syntax

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<UI.Models.GridVM>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.CampaignID)                    
        columns.Bound(p => p.CampaignStatus);  
        columns.Template(@<text></text>)
               .ClientTemplate(@"<a class=""k-grid-edit"" href=""\#"">Edit Master</a>"); 
        //Worked in master grid
    })            
    .Editable(editable => editable
        .Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
        .TemplateName("CampaignEdit")
        .Window(w =>
        {
            w.Width(400);
            w.Title("Edit Details");
        }))
    .Filterable()
    .Pageable()
    .Navigatable()
    .Sortable()                      
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .PageSize(20)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.CampaignID))
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetCampaigns", "Home"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateCampaign", "Home"))
    )
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("detailtemplate")       
)
<script id="detailtemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<UI.Models.DetailGridVM>()
        .Name("detailgrid_#=CampaignID#")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.CampaignDetailID);             
            columns.Bound(o => o.Notes);                
            columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedBy);
            columns.Template(@<text></text>)
                   .ClientTemplate(@"<a class=""k-grid-edit"" href=""\#"">Edit Detail</a>"); 
            // Does not work in detail grid
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(5)
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetCampaignDetails", "Home", new { campaignID = "#=CampaignID#" }))
            .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateCampaignDetails", "Home"))
            .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.CampaignDetailID))
        )
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .ToClientTemplate())
 </script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a column template that has the k-grid-edit class on it (use k-grid-delete for destroy):

```
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.CampaignID)                    
        columns.Bound(p => p.CampaignStatus);  
        columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate(@"<a class=""k-grid-edit"" href=""\#"">Edit</a>").Width(30);
        columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate(@"<a class=""k-grid-delete"" href=""\#"">Delete</a>").Width(30);
    })
```

or for smaller buttons and bootstrap:

```
    column.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate(@"<a class=""btn btn-info btn-xs k-grid-edit"" href=""\#"">Edit</a>").Width(30);
    column.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate(@"<a class=""btn btn-danger btn-xs k-grid-delete"" href=""\#"">Delete</a>").Width(30);
```

Comment: Not sure how that's going to work with the nesting. May need to examine what is rendered or use this technique: http://www.telerik.com/forums/template-inside-template

Comment: Found it. In order to change the detailgrid template i have to use escape chracters `.ClientTemplate(@"<a class=""k-grid-edit"" href=""\\\\#"">Edit Detail</a>");`

Comment: Do you know how the grid can change the text or better the icon when the button is clicked? thanks.

Comment: Try the edit event with some jquery.  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit

Comment: @SteveGreene thanks for this answer. if i have one grid column that is a template. How do i put a binded data (columns.Bound()...) & custom command (command.custom()...) in one column?

Comment: @mars-o Are you just trying to show one of the other fields? You could add a <span> <h1> etc. Hash syntax would work: `.ClientTemplate(@"<span>#= MyField #</span><a class=""btn btn-info btn-xs k-grid-edit"" href=""\#"">Edit</a>")`

Answer (score 0):

For example you can do that with `css` only:

```
td[role=gridcell] > a.k-button.k-button-icontext.k-grid-edit :hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
td[role=gridcell] > a.k-button.k-button-icontext.k-grid-edit {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```